# Bunched / Wrapped Cable

Tags: modeling

Im very new to Blender and was wondering if there is a way to model a wrapped cable that is held together in the middle (by a velcro Strap).

Like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The question is tagged [modeling](/questions/tagged/modeling) and is pretty big, and I'm not going to make a full-blown tutorial (I wouldn't be able, and is off-topic), so I'm focusing on the basics, trying to get to a decent starting point and ignoring the modeling of details and the shading.

The starting point is simply a curve. Start by adding a *Bezier curve*.

In *Edit mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select one of the two default handles and:

- <kbd>E</kbd> extrude it to the opposite side, making sure to add some variation/randomness
- repeat for several loops

  [image]
- rotate the handles in the view you've been using (select, <kbd>R</kbd>, repeat) to add randomness, or to align them (it really depends on how messy you want the cable)
- change view and add some random displacement of the handles in the perpendicular direction (select, <kbd>G</kbd>, repeat)

  [image]

You now want to add handles along the middle in order to control the shrinking. To do so:

- select all your handles (<kbd>A</kbd>)
- right click, *Subdivide*

  [image]
- Deselect all the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) and select only the middle ones using a box select (<kbd>B</kbd>)
- Shrink these handles along all axes except the long one, in my example: the *X* axis (<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>)

  [image]

The curve is done, now it requires some thickness.

- Exit *Edit mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), go to the *Curve properties*, and under *Geometry*, increase the *Bevel > Depth*.

  [image]

  You will probably see some overlaps, that can be fixed by moving some handles manually in edit mode.
- The velcro strap can be done starting from a plane and extruding it around the middle: while doing it, look around often to check that it's not intersecting or staying too far from the wires. With a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, it will then look softer

  [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! And I am sorry if I made any tagging mistakes!

Comment: You didn't make tagging mistakes! I meant: since you are interested in modeling, I'll focus on the modeling in my answer.